# WPF Textfield Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, textfield

I have a textfield in WPF and i want to validate the user input, i have found lots of examples that do bits of what i want but none that do it all.

It has to only allow numeric numbers (0-9)
Only one decimal place
Not allow multiple '.' which most solutions seem to allow,
Minimum number entry must be 
Maximum 999.9

Best solution i found so far is using a regex

```
new Regex(@"[^0-9.]+")
```

but this obviously doesn't limit number of decimal places or number of decimal points. Also no min or max

Can only one point me in the correct direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution might be to bind the text box to a `double` (or `decimal`) value which will give you the automatic digit and decimal point rules and add a `[Range]` attribute of your minimum and maximum values:

```
[Range(0, 999.9), "Error message"]
public double myValue { get; set; }
```

Or, if you want to actually prevent invalid input being entered in the first place, implement the `OnKeyDown` event handler for the text box and try to convert the input to a number. If it fails reject the input or if it succeeds but the number is outside your range reject the input. This is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I commonly use this approach for it's simplicity and flexibility. Just a humble concoction of Regex and plain-old conditional logic. This same pattern can be applied to almost any form of text input validation.

The ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Regex _inputRegex;
        public ViewModel()
        {
            _inputRegex = new Regex(@"^([0-9])+(([.])?([0-9])+)?$");
        }
        private string _input = "0";
        public string Input
        {
            get
            {
                return _input;
            }
            set
            {
               _input = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("Input");
               RaisePropertyChanged("InputValid");
            }
        }
        public bool InputValid {
            get
            {
                if(_inputRegex.IsMatch(_input))
                {
                    //If regex pattern is satisfied, this value is safe
                    double value = Convert.ToDouble(_input);

                    //so just apply conditional logic here
                    return value >= 0 && value <= 999.9;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }        
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

The View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" >
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        </Style>
        <Style  TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="default_textblock">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="error_textblock" BasedOn="{StaticResource default_textblock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Enter input: " Style="{StaticResource default_textblock}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Input, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Input not valid. Please enter a number between 0 and 999.9" >
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource error_textblock}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InputValid}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```